# Create new TYPO3 backend module menu group

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Straight ahead - I wish to create a custom module menu group in backend administration:

[image]

I have a lot of plugins, that work as modules and most if them are under WEB group and it's getting confusing. I wish to create a custom group like "COMPANY TOOLS" or "FRONTEND OPTIONS".

How do I do this in TYPO3? How do I create a custom module menu subgroup?

*PS: I'm currently using TYPO3 7.6.17, but will update to 8, once I fix plugin issues.*

*EDIT:* When setting the group parameter to new one, it only adds it to a blank group:

[image]

Comment: This question [is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348212/please-write-my-code-for-bounty), feel free to join into the discussion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the main module like the sub modules but with a shorter config array:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addModule('YourMainModule', '', '', '',
    [
        'name' => 'YourMainModule',
        'labels' => [
            'll_ref' => 'LLL:EXT:ext_key/Resources/Private/Language/Modules/locallang_mod.xlf'
        ]
    ]
);
```

The locallang_mod.xlf must contain the index `mlang_tabs_tab`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.0">
<file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2015-07-30T00:30:29Z"
      product-name="extension">
    <header/>
    <body>
        <trans-unit id="mlang_tabs_tab" xml:space="preserve">
            <source>Main module title</source>
        </trans-unit>
        <trans-unit id="mlang_labels_tabdescr" xml:space="preserve">
            <source>Main module description</source>
        </trans-unit>
    </body>
</file>
</xliff>
```

Hope, it works for you. Just fixed the same problem in l10nmgr with this code.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to create the group and add my extension to it. But I have 1 finall issue: *how do I correctly position it* ? It is always at the bottom and `after:web` or `top`doesn't change the groups position.

Comment: I looked into the code and it's not possible to position it in this method call. You can change the order by touching the array in  `$GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES']` which can be tricky and lead to bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at EXT:direct_mail. I suggest this at the best way to do so.
Here an example you need to adapt and insert in your ext_tables.php configuration file:

```
/**
 * Icon registry
 */
// Add a bunch of icons to icon registry
$iconIdentifiers = [
    'module-xyz',
    'module-xyz-mymodulename',
];
$iconRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry::class);
foreach ($iconIdentifiers as $iconIdentifier) {
    $iconRegistry->registerIcon(
        $iconIdentifier,
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\SvgIconProvider::class,
        ['source' => 'EXT:myextension_xyz/Resources/Public/Icons/' . $iconIdentifier . '.svg']
    );
}

/**
 * BE-module
 */
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
    // Add module 'xyz' after 'Web'
    if (!isset($GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES']['xyz'])) {
        $temp_TBE_MODULES = [];
        foreach ($GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES'] as $key => $val) {
            if ($key == 'web') {
                $temp_TBE_MODULES[$key] = $val;
                $temp_TBE_MODULES['xyz'] = '';
            } else {
                $temp_TBE_MODULES[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        $GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES'] = $temp_TBE_MODULES;
        $GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES']['_configuration']['xyz'] = [
            'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:myextension_xyz/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_module.xlf',
            'name' => 'xyz',
            'iconIdentifier' => 'module-xyz'
        ];
    }
    // Register module
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
        'Vendor.myextension_xyz',
        'xyz',
        'Mymodulename',
        'bottom',
        [
            'MyControllerOne' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
            'MyControllerTwo' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
        ],
        [
            'access' => 'user,group',
            'icon' => 'EXT:myextension_xyz/Resources/Public/Icons/module-xyz-mymodulename.svg',
            'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:myextension_xyz/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_module_mymodulename.xlf',
        ]
    );
}
```

Adapt names from my example:

- myextension_xyz ... Your extension name (extension key)
- xyz ... a short name, compare to your extension name
- Vendor ... Your vendor name
- Mymodulename ... Give your module a name (fx. 'Management')
- MyControllerOne, MyControllerTwo ... Your backend controller classes

You need to add following files to your extension:

- ../Resources/Private/Language/locallang_module.xlf
- ../Resources/Private/Language/locallang_module_mymodulename.xlf
- ../Resources/Public/Icons/module-xyz.svg
- ../Resources/Public/Icons/module-xyz-mymodulename.svg

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following code in your extensions `ext_tables.php`.

```php
<?php
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addModule(
    'yourcustomnewmodulename',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    [
        'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/Resources/Private/Language/Backend/MainModule.xlf',
        // See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Icon/Index.html
        'iconIdentifier' => 'your-registred-icon-from-IconRegistry'
    ]
);
```

Now you can use this new main module using the key `yourcustomnewmodulename` instead of `web`.

The MainModule.xlf should contain the keys; `mlang_labels_tablabel`, `mlang_labels_tabdescr` and `mlang_tabs_tab`. Example below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2012-10-17T19:30:32Z" product-name="extbase">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="mlang_tabs_tab" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Company Tools</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="mlang_labels_tabdescr" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Description used for about screen, what does the extension do?</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="mlang_labels_tablabel" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Company Tools</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

---

ps. If you want to see a live version, i did similar functionality in `EXT:my_user_management` [here](https://github.com/koninklijke-collective/my_user_management/blob/master/ext_tables.php), but has some legacy for 6.2.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I relate `yourcustomnewmodulename` to the MainModule.xlf so that I see Group Name also? Currently It created me a new group but without a title: http://prntscr.com/ey7tg7

Comment: Please check the extension my_user_management to see a working example :-)